# How can I get dynamically web content using Perl?

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

This is kind of tricky. There is this webpage which, I am guessing, uses some kind of AJAX to pull out content based on the search query. When I fetch the page using get in Perl, it fetches the script code behind the php/html, but not the results which are displayed when  the query is searched manually. I need to be able to fetch the content of the results page. Is there anyway to do this in Perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/) and the [`WWW::Selenium`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Test-WWW-Selenium/lib/WWW/Selenium.pm) module in Perl.  With them you can control a real web browser.

Another option is [`WWW::HtmlUnit`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-HtmlUnit/lib/WWW/HtmlUnit.pm) which uses the HtmlUnit Java library to execute the JavaScript without a web browser.  `WWW::HtmlUnit` uses [Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Inline-Java/Java.pod) to give Perl access to the library.  I have found that when installing, it is best to say No to the question "Do you wish to build the JNI extension?".

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing tests that need to check the rendered page, you can have a look at Schwern's [javascript-tap-harness](http://github.com/schwern/javascript-tap-harness/tree/master), which works with Selenium and handles all the scaffolding.

I also found [Using WWW::Selenium To Test Or Automate An Ajax Website](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=720018) pretty useful.